# apache-spark org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException: Cannot receive any reply in 120

Tags: apache-spark

I has configured a spark cluster in standalone mode. I can see that both workers are running, but when I start a spark-shell I have this problem:
Configuration of spark cluster is automatic.

```
val lines=sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4))
```

this work ok the new rdd has created but when I start the next task

```
lines.take(2).foreach(println)
```

I have this error that i cant solve:

Output:

```
 16/02/18 10:27:02 INFO DAGScheduler: Got job 0 (take at :24) with 1 output partitions
 16/02/18 10:27:02 INFO DAGScheduler: Final stage: ResultStage 0 (take at :24)
 16/02/18 10:27:02 INFO DAGScheduler: Parents of final stage: List() 
 16/02/18 10:27:02 INFO DAGScheduler: Missing parents: List() 
 16/02/18 10:27:02 INFO DAGScheduler: Submitting ResultStage 0 (ParallelCollectionRDD[0] at parallelize at :21), which has no missing parents
 16/02/18 10:27:03 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0 stored as values in memory (estimated size 1288.0 B, free 1288.0 B)
 16/02/18 10:27:04 INFO MemoryStore: Block broadcast_0_piece0 stored as bytes in memory (estimated size 856.0 B, free 2.1 KB)
```

A minute and a half later:

```
16/02/18 10:28:43 WARN NettyRpcEndpointRef: Error sending message [message = RemoveExecutor(0,java.io.IOException: Failed to create directory /srv/spark/work/app-20160218102438-0000/0)] in 2 attempts org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeoutException:
Cannot receive any reply in 120 seconds. This timeout is controlled by spark.rpc.askTimeout
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout.org$apache$spark$rpc$RpcTimeout$$createRpcTimeoutException(RpcTimeout.scala:48)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:63)
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.RpcTimeout$$anonfun$addMessageIfTimeout$1.applyOrElse(RpcTimeout.scala:59)
    at scala.runtime.AbstractPartialFunction.apply(AbstractPartialFunction.scala:33) 
    at scala.util.Failure$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Try.scala:185)
    at scala.util.Try$.apply(Try.scala:161)
    at scala.util.Failure.recover(Try.scala:185)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:324) 
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$recover$1.apply(Future.scala:324) 
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32)
    at org.spark-project.guava.util.concurrent.MoreExecutors$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(MoreExecutors.java:293) 
    at scala.concurrent.impl.ExecutionContextImpl$$anon$1.execute(ExecutionContextImpl.scala:133) 
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40) 
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248) 
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.complete(Promise.scala:55) 
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.complete(Promise.scala:153) 
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235) 
    at scala.concurrent.Future$$anonfun$map$1.apply(Future.scala:235) 
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.run(Promise.scala:32) 
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.processBatch$1(Future.scala:643) 
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply$mcV$sp(Future.scala:658)
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Future.scala:635) 
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$Batch$$anonfun$run$1.apply(Future.scala:635) 
    at scala.concurrent.BlockContext$.withBlockContext(BlockContext.scala:72) 
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$Batch.run(Future.scala:634) 
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.scala$concurrent$Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$$unbatchedExecute(Future.scala:694) 
    at scala.concurrent.Future$InternalCallbackExecutor$.execute(Future.scala:685) 
    at scala.concurrent.impl.CallbackRunnable.executeWithValue(Promise.scala:40) 
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryComplete(Promise.scala:248) 
    at scala.concurrent.Promise$class.tryFailure(Promise.scala:112) 
    at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryFailure(Promise.scala:153) 
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anon$1.run(NettyRpcEnv.scala:241) 
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) 
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) 
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) 
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Cannot receive any reply in 120 seconds 
    at org.apache.spark.rpc.netty.NettyRpcEnv$$anon$1.run(NettyRpcEnv.scala:242) ... 7 more
```

In one worker, I can see this log error :

```
Invalid maximum head size: -Xmxm0M could not create JVM
```

and also I can see a some problem I think that is related to a problem with binding a port or something like this.

Comment: You have to review your spark conf. Ensure both workers can connect by ssh without password. and check that Xmxm0M

Comment: yes both can connect without password, it is a requirement to set up a cluster in standalone mode. I can see in the UI that the two worker are alive. But when i start a task fail. I can see in the UI the app is launched but the memory per worker is 0. I change spark.executor.memory=1g but i still see 0 MB per node. I am very confuse about this

Comment: could you share your spark_env.sh?

Comment: i solve the problem apparently!!! I have a problem in spark_env.sh one of the variables are deprecated and another problem was that i have a variable with the exevutor memory but when i launched the app i see this paramater with the value0 but i launched the spark-shell with parameter --executor-memory=1g and after i launched a task and this task has executed succesfully with one of the worker.

Comment: Can you tell which one was deprecated?

Comment: i think that spark.executor.instances...when you launch spark in the log output the program warn you of it.

Answer (score 4):

The problem can be in area of ports visibility between spark cluster and client instance.

It is strange from user side but that is the feature of Spark architecture - each Spark node should see client instance and specific port defined by `spark.driver.port` in SparkContext configuration. This option by default is empty and it's mean that this port will be chosen randomly. As a result with default configuration each Spark node need to see any port of client instance. But you can override `spark.driver.port`.

It can be a problem if your client machine is behind firewall or inside docker container for example. You need to open this port outside

Answer (score 1):

If you are working on VM, you need to have at least 2 CPU processors. You have to set in VM configurations.